# Is it bad to have both www and the naked domain indexed in Google? Should both be added to webmaster tools?

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, subdomain, search-engine-indexing

Currently when searching on Google, the `www.example.com` version will appear as opposed to `example.com`.

I realize that isn't a big deal, however it made me wonder if I should do some of the same things for `www` that I currently do for the main domain:

- Creating sitemaps
- Adding `www.example.com` to Google Webmaster Tools

Does Google consider doing so to be spamming?  Will it make a difference to my rankings?

Comment: Doing it in GWT should be enough. But it's always good to be consistent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommended either using the `www` or `non-www` and stick with it. Set a preferred URL in Webmaster Tools and then 301 to either your `www` or `non-www`.

The reason for this would be Google would see both the `non-www` and `www` sites as two separate websites. If the content is exactly the same, then you could be penalized with duplicate content.